# for/fold Throwing Arity Mismatch Exception

Tags: racket

I am working through the book Beautiful Racket. I am trying to create a language of my own in a functional manner, following the chapter "Follow the grammar: bf".

I have condensed what I think is my issue into the following program:

```
#lang racket

(define (fold-funcs control-list fruit-funcs)
  (for/fold ([current-list control-list])
            ([fruit-func (in-list fruit-funcs)])
    (apply fruit-func current-list)))

(define (driver)
  (define init-list (list))
  (display (fold-funcs init-list (list
                                  (lambda (lst) (cons "apple" lst))
                                  (lambda (lst) (cons "banana" lst))))))
```

When I issue the following in the Interactions window (in DrRacket):

```
(driver)
```

I expect to get the following:

```
'("banana" "apple")
```

And indeed I can get that by issuing the following in the Interactions window:

```
((lambda (lst) (cons "banana" lst)) ((lambda (lst) (cons "apple" lst))(list)))
```

However, I actually get the following error:

```
...arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 0
```

I know what that means. It's saying I tried to execute a procedure that expects a single argument without providing that argument. But I can't see how that is the case. fold-funcs is being passed an empty list which serves as the accumulator and a list of functions which take one argument and return a list. (Technically, cons returns a pair, but I checked, and the following returns #t:

```
(list? (cons "apple" (list)))
```

I would like to know why the above program does not work.

Comment: `apply` here is not doing what you think it is doing. I believe you just want `(fruit-func current-list)`, not `(apply fruit-func current-list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your close, but are misusing [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29). To a first approximation, the `apply` function takes two arguments: a function, and a list. It then applies<sup>1</sup> the function to the arguments of the list as if they were passed in directly one at a time.

For example, the following two blocks of code are equivalent:

```
> (apply (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '(1 2))
3
```

and

```
> ((lambda (x y) (+ x y) 1 2)
3
```

Note how in one case we passed in the 'list' `'(1 2)`, while in the other we gave `1` and `2` as separate arguments.

In your `fold-funcs` function, you are using apply:

```
(define (fold-funcs control-list fruit-funcs)
  (for/fold ([current-list control-list])
            ([fruit-func (in-list fruit-funcs)])
    (apply fruit-func current-list)))
```

Which assumes that `current-list` contains the arguments passed in one by one to `fruit-func`. However, because `fruit-func` expects a single argument, the list itself, you are going to get an arity mismatch. Instead, if you remove the `apply` and just call `fruit-func` directly, then `driver` works as expected:

```
(define (fold-funcs control-list fruit-funcs)
  (for/fold ([current-list control-list])
            ([fruit-func (in-list fruit-funcs)])
    (apply fruit-func current-list)))
```

and now...

```
> (driver)
'(banana apple)
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Bad pun, I know...</sub>